# How to pass data from one variable in props to another in React app?

Tags: reactjs, closures, dataflow

```
class StarRating extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
}

 log = (selected) => {
  console.log(selected)
}

  render() {
        return <div>
          <Star
          selected = {true}
          doClick={() => this.log(this.selected)}
          />
          <Star />
          <Star/>
          <Star/>
          <Star/>
          </div>
        }
}
```

I need to pass "selected", that is "true" in my case to log, but it's written "undefined", what should I change?

This is Star component.

```
const Star =  ({selected, doClick=f=>f}) =>
<div className = {(selected) ? "star selected" : "star"} onClick={doClick}></div>

Star.propTypes = {
selected: PropTypes.bool,
doClick: PropTypes.func
}
export default Star
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct your StarRating component like below

```
class StarRating extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        selected: false
      }
  }

   log = () => {
    this.setState({
        selected: true
    });
  }

    render() {
          return <div>
            <Star
            selected = {this.state.selected}
            doClick={this.log}
            />
            <Star />
            <Star/>
            <Star/>
            <Star/>
            </div>
          }
  }
```

And

```
const Star =  ({selected, doClick}) => <div className = {(selected) ? "star selected" : "star"} onClick={doClick}></div>

Star.propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.bool,
  doClick: PropTypes.func
}
export default Star;
```

Comment: thanx for you answer, somehow is it possible to pass data whithout state? Just from selected = {true} to doClick={() => this.log(this.selected)}?

Comment: It's a component so you should not do that way. Whatever I suggested is the right way